# Angular JS UI-Router Reload on Same Page Issue and Open Link in New Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

**I have a Navbar in my Main Page.Whenever I right click on any link (exp:Add Company) and open it in New Tab, it shows the dashboard page in new tab and also when i am on Add Company or Update Company page other than Dashboard and i just Reload the page, it still shows the dashboard page after reload.**

**I want, when i am on Add Company page and on refresh ,it still shows me the same page(Add Company Page not Dashboard) and same thing for Open in New Tab.**

My Main Page looks like this :

```
<ul class="navigation navigation-main navigation-accordion">
   <li class="navigation-header"><span>Main</span> <i class="icon-menu"></i></li>
   <li ng-class="{active : isActive('/dashboard')}"><a ui-sref="dashboard" contextmenu="customMenu"><i class="icon-home4"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
   <li ng-class="{active : isActive('/addCompany')}"><a ui-sref="addCompany"><i class="icon-plus3"></i> <span>Add Company</span></a></li>
   <li ng-class="{active : isActive('/updateCompany')}"><a ui-sref="updateCompany"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> <span>Update Company</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Routes are Defined through UI-Router as :

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');

$stateProvider

    // Home route
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        views: {
            '': { 
                    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html' ,
                    controller : 'WelcomeCtrl'
                },
            'columnOne@dashboard': { 
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            }
        }
    })

    // Update Company
    .state('updateCompany', {
        url: '/updateCompany',
        views: {
            '': { 
                    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html' ,
                    controller : 'WelcomeCtrl'
                },
            'columnOne@updateCompany': { 
                templateUrl: 'views/updateCompany.html',
                controller: 'updateController'
                }
        }
    })

    // Add Company
    .state('addCompany', {
        url: '/addCompany',
        views: {
            '': { 
                    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html' ,
                    controller : 'WelcomeCtrl'
                },
            'columnOne@addCompany': { 
                templateUrl: 'views/addCompany.html',
                controller: 'addListController'
            }
        }
    });
 });
```

**Update :**

When I remove this code from my Route File :

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
   $locationProvider.html5Mode({
   enabled: true,
   requireBase: false
  });
}]);
```

My Whole Issue is Resolved after removing this code but now the URL looks like :

> http://localhost:8080/#!/dashboard

**I dont want this # in the URL.**

Comment: Try change to `ui-sref="/dashboard"`  and `ui-sref="/addCompany"` , ...

Comment: from your `routes`, every state has the `dashboard template`

Comment: Now, I get this Error: Could not resolve '/dashboard' from state 'addCompany' @hadiJz

Comment: I can't use # tag as, I have set this: $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });  @hadiJz

Comment: @NishiGaba, have you checked my comment above? every route has dashboard template.

Comment: I am loading other templates (Add Company or Update Company) in this content container in the Dashboard Page through **ui-view** as :                                     `<div class="content">
                <div ui-view="columnOne"></div>
 </div>`                                                                                                            @Sravan

Comment: I suspect `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');`
this line is doing that. once comment it and check if it is the culprit

Comment: Still, the issue is same. @Sravan

Comment: In your route change `'columnOne@updateCompany'` to `'columnOne'`
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-views

Comment: Thanks @Sravan for your time. There is an update in my question.Do you have some suggestions regarding this problem ?

Comment: Thanks @hadiJz for your time. There is an update in my question.Do you have some suggestions regarding this problem ?

Comment: why remove `$locationProvider.html5Mode({..` from code ?

Comment: Without this, my main issue(Reload on same page and Open in New Tab) is resolved.I didn't find any other solution. Do you have any other solution @hadiJz ?

Comment: Have you tried my comment above? and checked that URL?

Comment: @Sravan , I am using nested views.So, I have to mention the State names as  `columnOne@updateCompany`